# populate json dynamically in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json object, structure is given below:

```
 var jsonObject={
         'a1' : [
         'a1v1',
         'a1v2',
         'a1v3'
         ],
         'a2' : [
         'a2v1',
         'a2v2',
         'a2v3'
         ],
         'a3' : [
         'a3v1',
         'a3v2'
         ]
    };
```

i can set value to the json object in above way. but i wanted to construct the same jsonObject with same structure dynamically through loop. I will send arraylist to js file to loop through and assign values to my jsonObject. Is it possible in jquery/javascript or i have to make my jsonObject in the controller?

Thanks.

Comment: its possible using jquery

Comment: thanks, can you help me? i am stucked in looping. i will send two arraylists. one for the key; a1,a2, a3. and for each key i will get values: a1v1 or a2v2... from another list.

Comment: Iterate over the arrayList and create the json in controller itself. There is no arrayList in js AFAIK.

Comment: Is your controller written in java?